Discard all keyword changes in Abaqus using a script
I regularly make manual changes to Abaqus input files after I create models.
I wrote a cript that adds step details and other details to the input files using Keyword editor python commands.
But after running my first batch of models I decided to re-write some parts of the inputfiles.
The problem is that I get conflicted or duplicate keyword blocks unless I discard all changes, even if I delete the input files themselves, as changes I make through the keyword editor tool are associated directly with the model.
Therefore, the only solution I found was to discard all edits. But I was only able to do this manually in the GUI.
I would like to put this in my script to automatically avoid any conflicting or duplicated keywrod blocks.
So far, I've only been able to do discard changes manually.
I could not figure out how to do this iteratively in a script as there does not seem to be a specific method in the Abaqus scripting manual.
